# solidity mapping check if element already exists

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I am creating an Election website using blockChain. And I want a mapping of voters for all voters. All voter are updated when a new voter is added but currently the everytime a new voter is added it just replaces. **I want to check if the voter already exist or not if not then add the voter to the mapping else reply voter already exists.**

current code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Election {
    uint public candidatesCount;
    uint public votersCount;

    struct Candidate {
        uint id;
        string name;
        string party;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    mapping(uint=> Candidate) public candidates;
    mapping(address => bool) public voted;
    
    
    function addCandidate(string memory _name, string memory _party) public{
        candidatesCount++;
        candidates[candidatesCount] = Candidate(candidatesCount, _name, _party, 0);
    }
    

    function addVoter() public {
        voted[msg.sender] = false;
    }
    
    function vote(uint _candidateId) public {
        require(!voted[msg.sender], "You have already voted");
        require(candidates[_candidateId].id != 0, "Candidate does not exist");
        voted[msg.sender]= true;
        candidates[_candidateId].voteCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete this function as it introduces a vulnerability, where voters can change their vote, freely and bypass your check.

```js
    function addVoter() public {
        voted[msg.sender] = false;
    }
```

this `mapping(address => bool) public voted;` initialized the key pair mapping value to `false`

you already implemented that check within your function?

```js
 function vote(uint _candidateId) public {
        //this is already checking if they voted
        require(!voted[msg.sender], "You have already voted");
        require(candidates[_candidateId].id != 0, "Candidate does not exist");
        //this marks the sender as they have voted preventing them to vote again
        voted[msg.sender]= true;
        //this line doesn't seem secure as is it a public function allowing users to enter in any `_candidateId`
        candidates[_candidateId].voteCount++;
    }
```

Any user can enter any `_candidateId` can override your method of tracking the vote count.

It doesn't really seem like your saving the value of their vote for whatever they are voting on as in "yay" or "nay"; unless your counting voting as a "yay" and not as "nay"